# In OpenGL, how do I use glGetTexImage to get pixel data for a face of a texture of type GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am actually surprised that the [OpenGL Docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) say that this is possible, since it doesn't give any information on how to actually call glGetTexImage for a cubemap texture array. Is this actually possible?

It looks like [glGetTextureSubImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTextureSubImage.xhtml) is built for this, but that is unfortunately not supported in OpenGL 4.3, which I'm using. Surely there most be a way to achieve this that's not such a recent addition to the API.

Answer (score 1):

> I am actually surprised that the OpenGL Docs say that this is possible

It does not say that. You can retrieve a mipmap level from a cubemap array, just like you can for a 2D array, or a 3D texture. But this means getting *all* faces of every layer for that mipmap level, just as it does for 2D arrays and 3D textures.

If you want *only* one face from only one layer (which you can do for a non-array cubemap by using one of the face targets), then you will need to isolate this layer/face from the cubemap array. Specifically, you need to [create a 2D view texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_views) of the cubemap array that includes only that layer/face. You can perform `glGetTexImage` from that.

Comment: I'm actually okay with getting all of the data at once, since I can just process it on the CPU side. Are you saying that if I call `glGetTexImage` with `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY`, I will simply get the pixel data for everything in the entire texture array, i.e., I'll get a single buffer with each face of each cubemap? If so, I'll give that a go, and maybe implement a view texture later since that looks elegant.